# MonkeyTalk : http://localhost:16862/fonemonkey: Connection refused

Tags: monkeytalk

I am trying to run my IOS test cases using Monkey talk and it started giving me error as :

to localhost:16862/fonemonkey: Connection refused

This was not happening earlier and after few days when i started working back on monekytalk this error started coming.

Please help me on this as i need to automate My IOS app .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16862 is the Android playback port. This would indicate that MonkeyTalk thinks it is trying to talk to an Android device or emulator, rather than iOS. Take a look at the connection menu in the MonkeyTalk IDE.